# Nested for loops 0123

Tags: java, nested-loops

I need to create a nested for loops that gives the following output,

```
0
 1
  2
   3
```

This is what I have, but for the second test, `userNum` is replaced by 6 and obviously my code fails.. help?

```
    public class NestedLoop {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
      int userNum  = 0;
      int i = 0;
      int j = 0;

       for(i = 0; i <= userNum; i++){
        System.out.println(i);

           for(i = 1; i <= userNum; i++){
           System.out.println(" " +i);

              for(i = 2; i <= userNum; i++){
               System.out.println("  " +i);

                 for(i = 3; i <= userNum; i++){
                 System.out.println("   " + i);

          }
         }
        }
       }
         return;
   }
}
```

Comment: You should explain the relationship between userNum and the desired output.

Comment: userNum is replaced by 6? It's never 6 anywhere. It's 0.

Comment: The computer(my online textbook) is inputting a number for userNum and my code needs to be able to print the numbers in the format as shown through the given value of userNum.

Answer (score 1):

I think (it's a guess, though) that you're looking for this.

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
  int limit = 6;

  for(int i = 0; i <= limit; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
      System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.println(i);
  }
}
```

The reason why your approach fails is, as I see it, that you are looping through the numbers to show (which is right) **but** you fail to loop up on the number of spaces (which I resolved by relating the inner loop's limit to the outer loop's current value.

Comment: You're exactly right (save for the fact that it really *should* be `j < i`), but you should explain *why* this is right.

Answer (score 0):

Let's talk a bit about what your intention is with these loops.

The inner loop is meant to produce an arbitrary number of spaces, depending on what number you're iterating on.  So if you're on number 0, you produce no spaces, and if you're on 1, you produce one space, and so forth.  The other caveat is that they all *must* appear on the same line, so `System.out.println` is the incorrect choice.

You would want to use `System.out.print` to print out the spaces.  So let's write that.

```
for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

This will print out six spaces unconditionally.  What that condition *is* depends on the current number we're iterating on.  That comes from your outer loop.

You only need to define a loop that starts from an arbitrary starting point - like 0 - and then loop until you are at *most* your ending number.  For this, your current loop is sufficient:

```
for(i = 0; i <= userNum; i++) {

}
```

Now, we need to bring the two pieces together.  I leave the figuring out of the question mark and what to print *after* you've printed the spaces as an exercise to the user, bearing in mind that you must stop printing spaces after you've reached your number.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= userNum; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < ?; j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyse the task 
In every line, we should print a number and different number spaces in the front of the number.
For that, we need two loops - one outer to iterate from 0 to N and one inner to add spaces in front of the number.

```
private static void method1(int userNum) {
    int nummSpaces = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= userNum; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nummSpaces; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        nummSpaces++;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

In this solution, we have variable `numSpaces` which used to count the number of spaces in front of the number. It is unneeded - we can use variable `i` for that purpose.

```
private static void method2(int userNum) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= userNum; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Let's analyses once again the output
 - the fist line: printed zero spaces and number 0
 - the second line: printed one space and number 1
 - the third line: printed two spaces and number 2
 - and so on

Finally, we can use just one variable, which contains spaces and after that print the length of it:

```
private static void method3(int userNum) {
    for (String spaces = ""; spaces.length() <= userNum; spaces += " ") {
        System.out.println(spaces + spaces.length());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

C/C++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

int userNum;
int i;
int j;

cin >> userNum;

for (i = 0; i <= userNum; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        cout << " ";
    }
    cout << i << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.